# How to ignore html in aurelia

Tags: html, aurelia

I'm trying to write a simple site which lists some code and some html and provides a bit of styling and an explanation. How do I add HTML on the server to my document without aurelia trying to parse this? I do not use a view-model, just plain HTML.

For example, I'm using Prism to highlight the following code:

```
<span>${firstName}</span>
```

but, this code ends up as:

```
<span></span>
```

in my document. Is there a way for me to tell aurelia to skip certain parts of the html? To make the question harder, I include these pieces of code from an actual source files (using swig includes) so I can't manually add attributes; I want to keep the html "as is". I can however wrap it in a custom element but I would prefer not to.

What I've tried (will list more options as I try them):

- Wrapping the html in a script tag. Hoped auralia would leave that alone, but no dice.
- Escaping the HTML

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Reading your question again, I may have misunderstood. Look like you're talking about some server side include before the generated HTML is sent to client side and processed by Aurelia.

Comment: Yes indeed, I've just tried to clarify it in a comment below your answer.

Comment: Sorry then, I don't have a better idea than using custom element, which is not your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do this. (16-05-2016)

The other two answers are work-arounds and should be used.

- [qtuan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37211570/1654375)
- [Mr. Baudin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37222625/1654375)

Answer (score 2):

This is quite straightforward if you are willing to use a custom element.

Here's a suitable custom element:

```
import {  noView, processContent } from "aurelia-framework";

@noView()
@processContent(false)
export class AureliaIgnoreCustomElement {

}
```

You simply use it like this

```
<aurelia-ignore>${firstName}</aurelia-ignore>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML string is stored in a property, you can use `innerhtml` binding. For example:

**View model**

```
this.htmlProperty = '<span>${firstName}</span>';
```

**View**

```
<div innerhtml.bind="htmlProperty | sanitizeHTML"></div>
```

or

```
<div innerhtml="${htmlProperty | sanitizeHTML}"></div>
```

From the [documentation](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/cheat-sheet/5):

> Binding using the innerhtml attribute simply sets the element's
>   innerHTML property. The markup does not pass through Aurelia's
>   templating system. Binding expressions and require elements will not
>   be evaluated.
>
> Always use HTML sanitization. We provide a simple converter that can
>   be used. You are encouraged to use a more complete HTML sanitizer such
>   as sanitize-html .

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not exactly my use-case. I have a big glob of html, inside this html I have something like {% include 'my-file.html' %} which is rendered with swig (on the server). This content is inside a <pre><code>...</code></pre> so there is no way to bind this through the innerhtml.

Answer (score 0):

As of this moment it seems impossible to ignore parsing of certain DOM nodes in aurelia. At least it seems unlikely, so I'm adding an alternative to the mix:

I've created a custom attribute called *getContent* which takes a URL, retrieves the HTML and inserts it into the innerHTML of the element. With a custom element you could expand on qtuan's answer and bind the innerHTML to this "fetched" content.

```
import {customAttribute, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

@customAttribute('get-content')
@inject(Element, HttpClient)
export class GetContentCustomAttribute {
    constructor(element, http) {
        this.element = element;

        http.configure(config => {
            config
                .useStandardConfiguration();
        });

        this.http = http;
    }

    valueChanged(newValue) {
        var self = this;

        self.http.fetch(newValue)
            .then(response => {
                var reader = response.body.getReader();
                var decoder = new TextDecoder();
                var s = reader.read().then(utf => {
                    var html = decoder.decode(utf.value);
                    self.element.innerHTML = html;
                })

            });
    }
}
```

You can use this element like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>SWIG include example</h3>
    <pre class="line-numbers">
        <code class="language-markup">
            <script type="prism-html-markup"
                    get-content="/modules/components/lists/templates/list.html">
            </script>
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

The inner script tag is not needed for the html to get injected correctly, it is just there to keep things orderly.

I'm going to keep this question open for another few day and hope someone can answer the real question but for now there are two alternatives [qtuan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37211570/1654375) correct answer and mine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! I'm worried I have misleaded your solution searching with innerhtml. Recall that if what you want is to display a string `<span>${firstName}</span>` as it is, that means *BOTH*: the string should be HTML escaped, and Aurelia should not compile it. In fact, that can be achieved by a simple string interpolation, e.g `<div>${htmlProperty}</div>`. If you have this solution already working, maybe HTML escape has been done at server side.

Comment: Tbh, I just load the file as text, so not as `application/html` which (correct me if I'm wrong) automatically escapes the html. This solution should "just work" with the correct server side framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the very same syntax to output syntax as a string, which is what I'm doing with the same Prism.

```
<span>${'${myCodeVar}'}</span>
```